# Is there a YouTube URL parameter for continuously playing without timing out?

Tags: youtube

When trying to run a live video for display purposes using YouTube it times out overnight. Is there a code I can input into the URL that will allow the video to play continuously without stopping? Similar to having autoplay (`?autoplay=1`) in the URL?

Comment: Does it have to be in the URL?  It's easy to embed the YouTube in a web page that automatically refreshes itself.  E.g. Putting `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">` into the `<head>` section would reload the page every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and also based on my experience there's no way to disable the timeout. Though I believe there's a difference between the device you're using, such as computer browser versus phone app.